# Jsoup get absolute url from file and parse

Tags: android, parsing, url, jsoup

I want to load some txt file with links inside. I want to parse this links (some result - tags or so on) sequentially to list view. I start to try something like this (But my knowledge in `JSOUP` is poor).

```
 File input = new File("http://files.parsetfss.com/ce686da3-4464-47ec-ba73-24747f2da937/tfss-75cfc482-96ab-45f8-8d8b-80b40a5a0298-http.txt");
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://vao-priut.ru/");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url + http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some file on server available via browser you can simply read it line by line. To do it you can use for instance `URL` class and `Scanner`. When you will read each line you can parse it like you want.

```
 URL input = new URL("http://files.parsetfss.com/ce686da3-4464-47ec-ba73-24747f2da937/tfss-75cfc482-96ab-45f8-8d8b-80b40a5a0298-http.txt");
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(input.openStream());

 while(sc.hasNextLine()){
     String link = sc.nextLine();

     //since each line contains link to some resource 
     //now you can use jsoup to parse it
     Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
     //here place rest of code responsible for parsing
     //...
 }
```